# How can I resolve "class is not key value coding-compliant" error on button press?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

Basically, I am creating a To-Do list app and I have done everything about the code and layout, Using UITableView and Navigation controller, every time I press the add button to navigation to the other UIView it crashes, despite I have made a segment connecting it to the other view!
but I don't know what I am missing!
I have also mentioned it in the swift file.

[here it shows first when crashes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9rKh.jpg)

[Segments view for the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN1Ht.png)

here is the code for the `addTapped` button which is found in the add new to-do list

```swift
  class AddToDoViewController: UIViewController {

  var toDoTableViewController: ToDoTableViewController? = nil
    
    
  @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    
  @IBOutlet weak var prioritySegment: UISegmentedControl!
    
    
  @IBAction func addTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      let newToDo = ToDo()
      newToDo.priority = prioritySegment.selectedSegmentIndex
      if let name = nameTextField.text {
          newToDo.name = name
          if let name = nameTextField.text {
                     newToDo.name = name
                   }
      toDoTableViewController?.toDos.append(newToDo)
      toDoTableViewController?.tableView.reloadData()
      navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        
      }
  }
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a your IBAction - addTapped() linked to the Xib/Storyboard

Comment: Thank you for your question! I made some minor edits to your post, nothing major. Here's what I did. First, I phrased the title as a question so it's easier for people to find if they have a similar error. Second, I formatted your code a little differently and highlighted as Swift. That's it!  Thank you again!

Comment: It looks like your storyboard has a reference to an `@IBOutlet` named `addTapped`, but this outlet doesn't exist.  Check your button and make sure you haven't got a "referencing outlet" to a property of that name

Comment: yes I have linked it  @AjinkyaSharma

Answer (score 0):

Make @IBOutlet for your button.

Comment: I did , and connected it to the view controller